# File inaccessible in admin mode

Tags: c++, windows, boost, privileges

I have weird problem today...

We have a software running very well. Openning file, creating process every day...

But today, we figured out that if we run our software in *Administrator mode*... It doesn't work...

For example, when we try to create a process :

```
if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
#ifdef _UNICODE
    LPWSTR(m_Exec.c_str()),        // Command line
#else
    LPSTR(m_Exec.c_str()),
#endif
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    LPSTR(execFolder),           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
{
    cout <<  "[X] CreateProcess failed: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    HandleLastError("CreateProcess");
}
```

We have this error :

```
[X] CreateProcess failed: 2
[X] ERROR: CreateProcess: File specified not found.
```

And we have almost the same error in another part of our software when we try to load a simple config file with `boost::filesystem` :

```
boost::filesystem::fstream exists(fPath);
```

Return `file not found`.

But as I said, if we run the same software with the exact same operation but not in administrator mode, it works ...

*When we search on the internet, we find always the same thing : Pass in admin mode and it will work ... But for us it is the eact opposite...*

Any Idea ?

PS : We are on Windows 7 and we compile the software with Visual Studio 2012 Update 3.

Comment: Maybe the effect depends on the current working directory, and that has different contents for the Admin and for normal users?

Comment: It appears that it is only on a mounted file... Like `Z:/` who refers to C:/something... If we try to open the in `C:/something` it works but not on `Z:/` ...

Comment: Well there's your problem. That drive letter mapping is only defined for the users and not the Administrator.

Comment: Ok it turns out that effectively, if we redefine this letter to let the admin it works... I didn't know that. It is very helpful ! Post-it as an answer, I will accept it !